# define integer local with soot library

Tags: java, soot

I want to define Local with Integer type in soot library.I try to define local with this command

```
Local intLocal=Jimple.v().newLocal("intLocal",RefType.v("java.lang.Integer"));
IdentityStmt IST=Jimple.v().newIdentityStmt(intLocal,Jimple.v().newStaticFieldRef(Scene.v().getField("<java.lang.integer>").makeRef()));
```

but I got error

```
[Thread-3] ERROR heros.solver.CountingThreadPoolExecutor - Worker thread execution failed: oops <java.lang.integer>
```

can anyone explain how I can define local with integer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getField call is broken. You are passing an invalid reference. And you should be using an AssignStmt, not an IdentityStmt.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe it is very primitive question but can you suggest a valid reference.I try different thing but the problem still remains.

Comment: A field reference for System.out would look like this:
<java.lang.System: java.io.PrintStream out>